# Why is there an extra pixel in the smiley for the Grove LCD RGB Backlight from Seeed Studio?

Tags: lcd

While testing the [CustomCharacter.ino](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_LCD_RGB_Backlight/blob/master/examples/CustomCharacter/CustomCharacter.ino) example for the Grove LCD RGB Backlight from Seeed Studio on an Arduino 101 card, there is an extra pixel that appears above an eye of the smiley and the smiley gets shifted one row down also. (see attached picture just below, with some manual changes in the library, while trying to fix the problem)

[image: Example of the problem]

Actually, depending on the order of the characters assignments, the smiley is finally displayed correctly, such as in the following minimal working example, where the two `createChar()` assignments have been swapped (`1` is before `0`) and both smileys are displayed correctly:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "rgb_lcd.h"

rgb_lcd lcd;

byte smiley[8] = {
    0b00000,
    0b00000,
    0b01010,
    0b00000,
    0b00000,
    0b10001,
    0b01110,
    0b00000
};

void setup() 
{
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.createChar(1, smiley);
    lcd.createChar(0, smiley);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.write((unsigned char)0);
    lcd.write(1);
}

void loop() {}
```

If I happen to put `lcd.createChar(0, smiley);` back before `lcd.createChar(1, smiley);`, the error (the shift in the pixels rows + the extra activated pixel) occurs again for the second smiley.

Could anybody explain why this actually happens and, hopefully, give some way to fix the display?

Comment: There is an additional pixel row above the pattern you defined, and the last row is missing. You seem to have a one-off error in your code.

Comment: @thebusybee: Indeed! I did not spot that fact. I could not tell why that self-defined character is not displayed properly. I have checked the "frownie" character at the same location, for example, and that one is displayed correctly.

Comment: If the shown code reproduces the issue (the display does not match the code), then I'd say the library is faulty. Their initialization code looks wrong to me. You might want to correct it, do some research.

Comment: OK. The `setup()` function showed here is an adaptation of mine of the one original one in `CustomCharacter.ino`.

Comment: Well, I mean `rgb_lcd::begin()`. Such HD44780 compatible displays should to be initialized to 8-bit mode first. But it seems as if the method doesn't do this. However, as the LCD apparently is initialized, this has no consequences. But it is a smell about the quality of the library. -- The method `rgb_lcd::createChar()` looks OK. -- I would try to go one level deeper and bypass the library, using I²C directly to gain maximum control. -- What does the display show with your simplified program, both cases: 0 before 1, and 1 before 0? Are both smileys correct or wrong?

Comment: With the "1/0 order" for `rgb_lcd::createChar()`, both smileys are displayed correctly. Whereas, with the "0/1 order", the second one is displayed with the problems spotted before.

Comment: That is strange. The next step I would take is to insert some debugging messages over the serial line, just to watch `rgb_lcd::createChar()` doing its job correctly. Would you mind to try this? -- Alternatively, I would look into the generated assembly code just to be sure that it is correct. But this needs some expertise. -- Oh, and please [edit] your question to **add** the new information. New visitors will not necessarily read the comments down here.